# Single terraform code base for multiple environments

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure, terraform0.12+

I’ve looked around and seen multiple overlapping methods so now asking for direct input on an approach that addresses the following criteria:

- manage multiple terraform environments from a single terraform code base
- Each environment must have its own state file
- Remote state file storage
- Ability for other teams to data source resources created from this code base without having access to it (in their own team’s state files)

I’ve heard of file structures, workspaces, variable maps, terragrunt and .tfvars files. The goal is to push a resource from test to prod, and only have to feed in the configuration that differs which is normal size and scaling options WITHOUT having to update a bunch of different things. Can anyone paint a clear picture of an approach to accomplish this? What would the file structure look like? Detail is missing from much of what I’ve read online.

Comment: https://www.terraform.io/cli/workspaces

Answer (score 0):

This question gets asked a lot.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43048050/multiple-backends-for-different-environments-in-terraform?rq=1) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44288602/terraform-multiple-state-files-best-practice-examples?rq=1) for example.

In those links they describe using workspaces to create the separate state files which is required for the first pattern I'll mention below.

It really depends on the use case.

If the infrastructure should be identical, as in you change add a new Terraform resource and both environments change to create it simultaniously. Then the ideal process is to use a different .tfvar file based on the environment.

e.g.

```
my-project
|- customer-service
|-- main.tf
|-- customer1.tfvars
|-- customer2.tfvars
```

If however, you were doing a promotion process where you might want to create a resource first in one environment and then in a second (e.g. promotion from nonprod to prod), then the configuration should be separate.

e.g.

```
customer-project
|-- nonprod
|---- main.tf (this is not the same as main.tf below, add here first)
|-- prod
|---- main.tf (then add what you tested in nonprod to here changing the values)
```

I'll add a disclaimer that this is heavily opinionated but this is the approach I would take based on my experience.

Comment: The promotion process is what’s needed. Resources need to be validated prior to going through other environments. Very rarely would I want to just push it to all at once. 

I understand the multiple state file part or workspaces. What I’m less clear on is which approach (variable maps or tfvars or terragrunt) is best for managing all environments with the least code management overhead. I see the merits of terragrunt, but also don’t like the added dependency and syntax. Feels like if you use it, you’re all in. So leaning more towards tfvars or maps. Never really used either in this way

Comment: I also want to point out those links you provided to other questions on this topic are extremely dated.